# (c++) checking array of pointers for null value

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, null, initialization

I'm at a standstill with my conceptual understanding of the initialization of pointers.

I have created an array like this:

```
int *A = NULL;
A = new int[p];
```

Now trying to simulate inserting values this array, A.
Here is the catch, imagine if the array already has some values placed.

For example:

```
A[0]= 10;
A[1]= 4;
A[2]= NULL;
A[3]= 2;
```

How would I constrain an if statement to check if the array is null?

iterating through the array values with i and checking

```
if(A[i] == NULL){
cout << "hello";
}
```

Will never print that?

However! If I initialize the array then do this.

```
int *A;
A = new int[p];
for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    A[i] = 0;
}
```

It will allow me to catch that NULL value and perform my operations.

What is the difference between int *A = {0}; ( Not currently working for me)

and looping through, individually setting each value to 0?

Comment: Your array contains `int` values, don't use `NULL` with them. Actually don't use `NULL` in C++ in general, use `nullptr` when dealing with pointers instead. "If I initialize the array then do this." do what? your code snippet only shows array initialization. You should provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Define what do you mean by "_unfilled_" for an `int` type? Your array does not hold pointers to `int`s, it holds `int`s.

Comment: "Should I be doing this with vectors instead?" probably. To be honest "imagine if the array already has some values placed." doesn't really make a ton of sense, why would the values not be contiguous, where would the values come from? etc... If you want to hide certain values on iteration then just assign those "hidden" values `-1` and skip over them.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding. It made me realize my actual questions should have been. "Is there any way I could see which values were "empty" without actually putting in a number like "-1" or 0? For the odd case that a value of 0 or -1 would actually be inputted.

Comment: The solution would be different with different concrete cases, but the generic solution would be to use `boost::optional<int>` or roll your own, if you're feeling lazy, you could also just create an array of strong handles and check them for null `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>`.

Answer (score 0):

The *type* of each element of `A` is an `int`. It doesn't make much sense to use `NULL` as an element for an `int`, `NULL` is more to do with a pointer literal value; although from C++11 onwards, `nullptr` stands in for that.

Unless you're willing to use a crude "magic value" for an "unset" `int`, consider using `std::vector<boost::optional<int>>` as the type for `A`. You can then tell if an element has been explicitly set or not.

`boost::optional` is being emitted into a future standard (C++17) as `std::optional`, so refactor to that at the appropriate time. (Another approach prior to C++17 would be to borrow the source code from a future C++ standard library: `std::optional` is trivially implementable in C++11 onwards.)

References:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 and higher it is recommend to avoid `new/delete`. I recommend to use a appropriate container, such as `std::vector<int>`. When using std containers there is no need for NULL check.

If this container does not satisfy your need, a `std::unique_ptr` is still a better choice than a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

C++ allows you to "value-initialize" an array using the following syntax-

```
new int[size]()
```

As per ISO C++03 5.3.4 [expr.new]/15-

*A new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows:
If the new-initializer is of the form (), the item is value-initialized (8.5)*

Using the above approach you can modify your code as shown below-

```
int *A = NULL;
A = new int[p]();
if(A[i] == 0){
  //do whatever
}
```